# Transform array of records to summary or pivot using ramdajs

Tags: ramda.js

```
[
  {
    "door_id": 324,
    "action": "door open",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-30 10:34:44",
    "date": "2018-03-30"
  },
  {
    "door_id": 324,
    "action": "door close",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-30 10:39:44",
    "date": "2018-03-30"
  },
  {
    "door_id": 324,
    "action": "door open",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-30 10:59:44",
    "date": "2018-03-30"
  },
  {
    "door_id": 325,
    "action": "door open",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-31 14:59:44",
    "date": "2018-03-31"
  },
  {
    "door_id": 325,
    "action": "door close",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-31 15:00:44",
    "date": "2018-03-31"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to transform this array of objects into the expected format using ramda.js.

The open and close actions will **always** comes in sequence but not necessarily make a complete set (e.g. there's a log for *door opening*, but no log for *door closing* because the door is open)

I prefer more like step-by-step using mapper approach/partial function.

```
const expected = [
  {
    "door_id": 324,
    "date": "2018-03-30",
    "status" : "Open",
    "actions_set_count": 2,
    "actions": [
      {
        "open": "2018-03-30 10:34:44",
        "close": "2018-03-30 10:39:44",
        "duration": 300
      },
      {
        "open": "2018-03-30 10:59:44",
        "close": null,
        "duration": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "door_id": 325,
    "date": "2018-03-31",
    "status" : "Closed",
    "actions_set_count": 1,
    "actions": [
      {
        "open": "2018-03-30 14:59:44",
        "close": "2018-03-30 15:00:44",
        "duration": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What have i done so far but it far from complete

```
const isOpen = R.propEq('action','door open')
const isClosed = R.propEq('action','door close')


R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('date')),
  R.map(R.applySpec({
    "date": R.pipe(R.head(), R.prop('date')),
    "door_id": R.pipe(R.head(), R.prop('door_id')),
    "open" : R.filter(isOpen),
    "close" : R.filter(isClosed),
    "sets": R.zip(R.filter(isOpen),R.filter(isClosed))
  })),
)(logs)
```

Comment: @Ori Drori need your expertise. thanks in advance

Comment: @Scott Sauyet need your expertise. thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet OP updated with my works so far.

Comment: Why does the `date` field in the output come from the *first* action?  What if the open/close pair spanned midnight?  Wouldn't the *last* action, which presumably corresponds to `status` make more sense?

Comment: I haven't consider the possibility of the spanned midnight. but to keep it simple, lets say that this log only one day records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a transformation like this, when I can't think of something elegant, I fall back on `reduce`.  Using `groupBy` (and if necessary, `sortBy`) and `values` we can put the data together in an order that allows us to do then do a straightforward -- if a bit tedious -- reduction on it.

```js
const duration = (earlier, later) => 
  (new Date(later) - new Date(earlier)) / 1000

const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('door_id')),
  map(sortBy(prop('timestamp'))), // Perhaps unnecessary, if data is already sorted
  values,
  map(reduce((
    {actions, actions_set_count}, 
    {door_id, action, timestamp, date}
  ) => ({
    door_id, 
    date, 
    ...(action == "door open" 
      ? {
          status: 'Open',
          actions_set_count: actions_set_count + 1,
          actions: actions.concat({
            open: timestamp, 
            close: null, 
            duration: null
          })
        }
      : {
          status: 'Closed',
          actions_set_count,
          actions: [
            ...init(actions), 
            {
              ...last(actions), 
              close: timestamp, 
              duration: duration(last(actions).open, timestamp)
            }
          ]
        }
    )
  }), {actions: [], actions_set_count: 0}))
)

const doors = [
  {door_id: 324, action: "door open",  timestamp: "2018-03-30 10:34:44", date: "2018-03-30"},
  {door_id: 324, action: "door close", timestamp: "2018-03-30 10:39:44", date: "2018-03-30"},
  {door_id: 324, action: "door open",  timestamp: "2018-03-30 10:59:44", date: "2018-03-30"},
  {door_id: 325, action: "door open",  timestamp: "2018-03-31 14:59:44", date: "2018-03-31"},
  {door_id: 325, action: "door close", timestamp: "2018-03-31 15:00:44", date: "2018-03-31"}
]

console.log(transform(doors))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, sortBy, values, reduce, init, last} = ramda    </script>
```

There are other ways we could approach this.  My first thought was to use `splitEvery(2)` to get these in open-close pairs, and then generate the actions.  The trouble is that we would still need the actual original data to fill in the rest (`door_id`, `date`, etc.)  So I ended up with `reduce`.

Obviously this is far from elegant.  Part of that is that the underlying transformation is not particularly elegant (why the `actions_set_count` field, which is just the length of `actions`?), nor is the data (why have the `date` *and* `timestamp` fields?)  But I suspect that I've also missed things which would make for a nicer implementation.  I'd love to hear what those are.

Note that I chose to use the final `date` field rather than the initial one.  Sometimes that's easier to do in a `reduce` call, and it sounds as though that's not important yet.